ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework, how to set up a three way intersection table
I currently have two objects that have a many to many relationship
Type 1: School
Type 2: Compliance
I've got this code in my DBContext, which created the intersection table for these classes.
    builder.Entity<School>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Compliances)
        .WithMany(y => y.Schools)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("SchoolCompliances"));

This works well and I'm able to include compliances when I get schools from the db.
Now I need to add a third class. I need to add "Programs" into the mix.
Schools and Programs have a 1 to many relationship (currently implemented)
but now I need to add a many to many relationship between Compliances and Programs.
This is easy enough in pure sql terms, I can just add ProgramId to the SchoolCompliances table as a foreign key.
I have no idea, however, how I should go about setting this up in ASP with my DBContext and my classes so that when I get a compliance record, it is correlated to both school and program.
Any thoughts?
I could simply create a model class something like "SchoolProgramCompliance" and give it the three respective Id's as properties, and then have EF create that table, but it seems like this would require me to do a lot more explicit linking of those objects when I want to retrieve them from the database and insert them into the database.
So hopefully there is a graceful way to handle this?

Do schools and programs have their own compliances, or does a combination of school and program have compliances? Only in the latter case a three-way junction table is appropriate.

As you mention using the SchoolProgramCompliance is right choice for the many to many relationship.
You could try this below code to set the many to many relationship:
Compliance.cs:
namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models
{
    public class Compliance
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SchoolProgramCompliance> SchoolProgramCompliances { get; set; }

    }
}

EducationalProgram.cs:
namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models
{
    public class EducationalProgram
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SchoolProgramCompliance> SchoolProgramCompliances { get; set; }
    }
}

School.cs:
namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models
{
    public class School
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SchoolProgramCompliance> SchoolProgramCompliances { get; set; }

    }
}

SchoolProgramCompliance.cs:
namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models
{
    public class SchoolProgramCompliance
    {
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        public School School { get; set; }

        public int ProgramId { get; set; }
        public EducationalProgram Program { get; set; }

        public int ComplianceId { get; set; }
        public Compliance Compliance { get; set; }
    }
}

SchoolProgramComplianceDto.cs:
namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models
{
    public class SchoolProgramComplianceDto
    {
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        public int ProgramId { get; set; }
        public int ComplianceId { get; set; }
    }

}

SchoolProgramComplianceResponseDto.cs:
namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models
{
    public class SchoolProgramComplianceResponseDto
    {
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }

        public int ProgramId { get; set; }
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }

        public int ComplianceId { get; set; }
        public string ComplianceDescription { get; set; }

    }
}

SchoolProgramComplianceController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Data;
using SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models;

namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SchoolProgramComplianceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public SchoolProgramComplianceController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/SchoolProgramCompliance
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var data = await _context.SchoolProgramCompliances
                .Include(spc => spc.School)
                .Include(spc => spc.Program)
                .Include(spc => spc.Compliance)
                .Select(spc => new SchoolProgramComplianceResponseDto
                {
                    SchoolId = spc.SchoolId,
                    SchoolName = spc.School.Name,
                    ProgramId = spc.ProgramId,
                    ProgramName = spc.Program.Name,
                    ComplianceId = spc.ComplianceId,
                    ComplianceDescription = spc.Compliance.Description
                })
                .ToListAsync();

            return Ok(data);
        }


        // POST: api/SchoolProgramCompliance
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SchoolProgramComplianceDto model)
        {
            // Check if School, Program, and Compliance IDs are valid
            if (!await _context.Schools.AnyAsync(s => s.Id == model.SchoolId))
                return NotFound($"School with ID {model.SchoolId} not found.");

            if (!await _context.Programs.AnyAsync(p => p.Id == model.ProgramId))
                return NotFound($"Program with ID {model.ProgramId} not found.");

            if (!await _context.Compliances.AnyAsync(c => c.Id == model.ComplianceId))
                return NotFound($"Compliance with ID {model.ComplianceId} not found.");

            var entry = new SchoolProgramCompliance
            {
                SchoolId = model.SchoolId,
                ProgramId = model.ProgramId,
                ComplianceId = model.ComplianceId
            };

            _context.SchoolProgramCompliances.Add(entry);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetAll), new { id = entry.SchoolId }, entry);
        }
    }

}

SchoolsController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Data;
using SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models;

namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SchoolsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public SchoolsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSchools()
        {
            var schools = await _context.Schools
                .Include(s => s.SchoolProgramCompliances)
                .ThenInclude(spc => spc.Program)
                .Include(s => s.SchoolProgramCompliances)
                .ThenInclude(spc => spc.Compliance)
                .ToListAsync();

            return Ok(schools);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSchool(School school)
        {
            _context.Schools.Add(school);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetSchools), new { id = school.Id }, school);
        }
    }

}

ApplicationDbContext.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Models;

namespace SchoolProgramComplianceDemo.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EducationalProgram> Programs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Compliance> Compliances { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SchoolProgramCompliance> SchoolProgramCompliances { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // Configure the junction entity
            builder.Entity<SchoolProgramCompliance>()
                .HasKey(spc => new { spc.SchoolId, spc.ProgramId, spc.ComplianceId });

            builder.Entity<SchoolProgramCompliance>()
                .HasOne(spc => spc.School)
                .WithMany(s => s.SchoolProgramCompliances)
                .HasForeignKey(spc => spc.SchoolId);

            builder.Entity<SchoolProgramCompliance>()
                .HasOne(spc => spc.Program)
                .WithMany(p => p.SchoolProgramCompliances)
                .HasForeignKey(spc => spc.ProgramId);

            builder.Entity<SchoolProgramCompliance>()
                .HasOne(spc => spc.Compliance)
                .WithMany(c => c.SchoolProgramCompliances)
                .HasForeignKey(spc => spc.ComplianceId);

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }

}

In the above code i have set the SchoolProgramCompliance as an explicit entity with three foreign keys (SchoolId, ProgramId, ComplianceId) and corresponding navigation properties. you could refer this below link for more detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key
Relationships between three tables with Entity Framework
